# Approach to route encoded wcf request

Tags: wcf

In a laboratory environment I have three "applications": **A**, **B**, **C**.

**B** and **C** hosts the WCF chat service. **A** is just a client.

**A** application sees WCF service hosted on **B**, and **B** sees WCF serive hosted on **C**.
So **A** application can't send the message directly to **C**.

I use netTcpBinding with Message security, secured with an X509 certificate.
**A** app know the certificates of **B** and **C**.

I want to create a proxy for chat service of the **B** app, and send a message with some mark which tells **B** to route the message to **C** app. Also, I want the message to be encoded with **C** certificate, so the **B** can't read the message appointed to **C**.

The problem can be solved in many awful ways. I'm a little expirenced with WCF, so I need help to find a better solution.

Can you suggest the better approach to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Encode the message body, add an unencoded routing header to the payload and let service B route based on the routing header. Or implement [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have additional questions.

Comment: Those questions being?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with commenting. I post the "answer" with the question. :)

Comment: You should update your question with those questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have additional questions.
How to encode the message body?

On the client side I use this code

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding { Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.Message } };
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

//_foreignServiceCertificate - is the B certificate
//_foreignServiceUrl - is the url of the B service
var endpointIdentity =  EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(_foreignServiceCertificate.SubjectName.GetCommonName());
var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(_foreignServiceUrl), endpointIdentity);

//_thisPeerCertificate - is the A certificate
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IChatService>(binding, endPointAddress);
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = _thisPeerCertificate;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new ClientCertificateValidation(_foreignServiceCertificate);
IChatService serviceProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage { Message = message, MessageSender = _thisPeerCertificate };

serviceProxy.SendMessage(chatMessage);
```

You suggest to encrypt messsage body with **C** public key. And the message body will be additionaly encrypted by wcf infrastructure with **B** public key. Did I get it right?

Is it correct, what I can encode message body with custom implementation of the IEndPointBehavior and custom implementation of the IClientMessageInspector (the method beforesendrequest)?